# IIS URL Rewrite with wild card

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

I need to change current URL pattern (hotels/{City}) to more SEO friendly one villa-{city} and I need to add a wild card for cities. Any city name should allow by the site and previous URL pattern need to rewrite as new pattern. I tried the below rewrite and its working for redirection but it effects on other URL patterns like "hotels/{name}/{code}" too. How can I overcome this redirection effecting on other patterns?

Can someone help me with this?

I would like to know how can we determine whether we use {R:0} Or {R:1} for conditions and the purpose of adding "^" to patterns

```
<rule name="HotelToVilla" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="hotels/(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost:23617" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:23617/villa-{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: Add another rule to break early https://blog.lextudio.com/iis-url-rewrite-tip-break-free-adccdb4b9f2f

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the comment. I have added another wild card on the top of above rule. I set action type "None" for below pattern and it worked <match url="hotels/(.*)/(.*)" />. So only <match url="hotels/(.*)" /> will redirect to Villa-{R:1}. Thank you

Comment: You should post your own answer and accept it.